# Функция в тексте программы на ассемблере

Tags: java

Есть функция у меня в программе, преобразующая массив byte в массив String

```
String[] _SS_usb_temp = byteArrayToHexString(arg1).split(" ");
.....
public String byteArrayToHexString(final byte[] bytes) {
   sb = new StringBuilder();
   for (byte b : bytes) {
       sb.append(String.format("%02x", b & 0xFF)).append(" ");
   }
   return sb.toString().toUpperCase();
}
```

В секунду обрабатывается около 1000 пакетов. Возможно ли эту функцию для ускорения обработки массивов написать на ассемблере и вставить этот код в тексте java?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/jugru/blog/347200/

Comment: Сначала из массива байт делается одна длинная строка из строчных букв с пробелами в качестве разделителей, затем еще одна из заглавных, затем длинная строка разбивается на массив строк - по одной на каждый байт в исходном массиве. Вот из-за таких шедевров оптимизации у java плохая репутация.

Comment: Есть более оптимальный код? Покажите.
P.S. Код справляется с работой. Просто занимаюсь оптимизацией

Comment: Ну можно за один проход сразу присваивать каждому элементу из массива строк соотв. строку из таблицы. ¿А зачем вам вообще нужен массив с со строками, хранящими шестнадцатиричные представления байт в исходном массиве? ¿Это случаем не проблема XY?

Comment: Я получаю данные с каншины автомобиля, и далее обработка их идёт. Пакет приходит с несколькими сигналами, поэтому я его разбиваю на отдельные сигналы и далее обрабатываю каждый сигнал

Comment: ¿И какая связь с приведенным кодом? Чтобы обрабатывать пакеты с каншины строки вообще не нужны. И тем более не нужно преобразовывать байты в шестнадцатеричные строковые представления.

Comment: Ну мне то виднее, что и как приходит. И данные с каншины в hex. Если не знали. В hex и работаю с ними

Comment: Я бы переформулировал вопрос, чтобы он звучал "как можно оптимизировать функцию". Тут много чего можно добиться просто оптимизацией в джаве. Только ответ в этом духе не будет ответом на вопрос про ассемблер.

Comment: Это лишь малая часть кода. Буду потихоньку заниматься

Comment: Еще пара общих замечаний, если говорить именно о производительности. 1. для обработки байтов не нужно переводить их в строки (разве что целью обработки является именно получить строки чтоб их показать где-то или передать в другие системы именно в текстовом виде), можете поделиться зачем преобразовывать - интересно. 2. вы уверенны, что именно эта функция является узким местом обработки? Ведь если нет, то и ее оптимизация (тем более на ассемблере в ущерб читаемости и удобству сопровождения) для общего процесса ничего не даст.

Comment: Я получаю массив [68, 51, 34, 17, -118, 1, 0, 0, 55, -120, 86, 6, -84, 0, 0, 0], а мне для обработки нужен массив в виде 01 F6 08 00 E0 42 06 00 FF 0F FF. Который и является сигналом.
На эту функцию показывает инструмент Profiler

Comment: *"а мне для обработки нужен массив в виде 01 F6 08"* - ¿что вам мешает эти же значения обрабатывать прямо в исходных байтах?

Comment: Потому что сигналы в каншине в hex

Comment: Но в своё время как-то не подумал, посмотрю. Но разложите мне -120 на биты. Причем правильно

Comment: Нет, сигналы в каншине в байтах... десятичное или шестнадцатиричное может быть только их строковое представление.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Написать часть кода на ассеблере -- это, честно говоря, довольно удивительное желание. В принципе, есть возможность использовать функции, написанные на других языках, в том числе на ассемблере, см. напр. [википедию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface). Но во-первых, это не так просто, во всяком случае, для новичка, а во вторых, в большинстве случаев выигрыш будет не так уж велик.
В вашем случае это было бы стрельбой из пушки по воробьям.

В смысле быстродействия можно гораздо проще получить ощутимый результат, просто поняв, что именно мы хотим сделать, и аккуратно написав именно это. В вашем случае производительность теряется на операциях с длинными строками -- преобразование `StringBuilder`а в длинную строку, перевод этой строки в верхний регистр, и последующая разбивка результата на подстроки.

Эта же самая работа, которую делает ваш фрагмент кода, может быть сделана намного быстрее:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Ru_So_1248963_c {

  public static final int BYTE_COUNT = 2_500_000;
  private static final Random rand = new Random();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final byte[] bytes = getbytes();      // get them from wherever you need
    final String[] result = new String[bytes.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < 300_000; i++)     // warmup
      result[i] = hexByte1(bytes[i]);

    long time = System.nanoTime();        // Measure time
    for (int i = 0; i < BYTE_COUNT; i++)
      result[i] = hexByte1(bytes[i]);
    time = System.nanoTime() - time;

    System.out.format("v1: %,d байт конвертировано за %.3f мс,\n" +
                      "  скорость %,.3f байт в секунду\n\n",
                      BYTE_COUNT, time * 1e-6, BYTE_COUNT / (time * 1e-9));
  }

  /** Generates BYTE_COUNT random bytes */
  private static byte[] getbytes() {
    final byte[] bytes = new byte[BYTE_COUNT];
    rand.nextBytes(bytes);
    return bytes;
  }

  /** Hex digits */
  private static char[] HEX_CHARS = new char[] {
    '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F',
  };

  /** Converts the given byte to a hex string */
  private static String hexByte1(byte b) {
    final char[] chars = new char[2];
    chars[0] = HEX_CHARS[b >>> 4 & 0xF];
    chars[1] = HEX_CHARS[b & 0xF];
    return new String(chars);
  }

}
```

Результат на моей машине (i5-4460 3.20GHz):

```
v1: 2 500 000 байт конвертировано за 222,610 мс,
  скорость 11 230 424,892 байт в секунду
```

Однако и ваш код работает намного быстрее, чем 1000 исходных байт в секунду -- где-то в районе сотен килобайт в секунду, если входной массив не слишком мал и не слишком велик
(напр. от 10 000 до 10 000 000). Так что главная потеря быстродействия у вас где-то в другом месте, возможно там, где вы обрабатываете полученные строки.

Ну и скорей всего, как справедливо написали люди в комментариях, для решения вашей задачи можно обойтись и без возни с многочисленными строками. Много строк -- это всегда медленно, ведь каждая новая строка -- это выделение памяти под новый объект и потом последующая сборка мусора. К тому же, это крайне неэффективно по расходу памяти, на достаточно больших данных программа вообще может вылетать из-за переполнения кучи. Подумайте над тем, как обойтись без этого.

Comment: Использование массивов будет лучше, чем работа со строками?

Comment: Так нельзя ставить вопрос. Во-первых, смотря чего массив, а во-вторых, массивы и строки не взаимозаменяемы. Одна строка лучше, чем массив строк, а массив байтов (или целых) еще лучше. Где-то лучше строки, где-то лучше массивы символов, смотря что от них требуется.

Comment: Я бы хотел с вами пообщаться, слишком обширная тема, но не нашёл e-mail вашего

Comment: Stackoverflow не даёт емейлов, и правильно делает. Я тоже не могу дать свой email, по крайней мере в общедоступном месте. Попробуйте поискать собеседников где-нибудь на форумах.

Comment: Заметил, понимаю

Comment: Я переписал код, избавился от stringbuilder, в итоге я снизил нагрузке почти в 5 раз, спасибо за наводку!

Comment: @ArtyMorris Если ответ был полезен, можете отметить, что он принят

Answer (score -2):

Как вариант можно создать Массив bytes2 длиной 2*Длинаbytes преобразовать bytes к bytes2

```
// byte[] to string
   String s = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

// Либо так:
  

// Java 8 - Base64 class, finally.
// byte[] to base64 encoded string
   String s = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
```